# JS keeps redirecting me to a null page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this js script that will make the page fade in when the user enters, and fades out when the user clicks a link to another page. It works, but somehow I have my anchor links within the page and whenever I click the links, it takes me to the anchor and within a few seconds it redirects me to a null page like `localhost/website/null` 

here's the code:

```
jQuery('body').css('display', 'none');
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('body').fadeIn();
   jQuery('a').on('click', function(event) {
      var thetarget = this.getAttribute('target')
      if (thetarget !="_blank" ) {
         var thehref = this.getAttribute('href')
         event.preventDefault();
         jQuery('body').fadeOut(function(){
            window.location = thehref
         });
      }
    });
});
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('body').fadeIn();
}, 1000)
```

Comment: what is the error? you need to prevent the `null` page redirecting?

Comment: Yeah, how can I do that please ?

Comment: Your `thehref` variable is clearly returning a null value, but it'd be easier to debug if we can have some live code to test on.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: What other events do you have on those links?  Provide some HTML

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understanding the problem -- maybe there isn't an issue? Refer to the snippet below?

Meta/Sidenote: SO needs a better way of creating snippets for comments -- this shouldn't be an answer, but there's no better way to supply a SO-generated demo.

```js
jQuery('.container').css('display', 'none');

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $container = $('container').fadeIn();


  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var _target = this.getAttribute('target');

    if (_target != "_blank") { // (e.g., null, '_self')
      var _href = this.getAttribute('href');
      e.preventDefault();

      $('.container').fadeOut(function() {
        window.location = _href;
      });
    }
  });
});

setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery('.container').fadeIn();
}, 1000)
```

```css
.container {
  background: #09c;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}

a:nth-child(2n)::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <a href="//www.google.com" target="_self">_self (external link)</a>
    <a href="#foo" target="_self">_self (internal link)</a>
    <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">_blank (external link)</a>
    <a href="#foo" target="_blank">_blank (internal link)</a>
    <a href="//www.google.com">No target (external link)</a>
    <a href="#foo">No target (internal link)</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, reprehenderit, nostrum. Tempora totam, iusto, inventore cupiditate hic quam quas explicabo dolore mollitia eius ullam rerum minus placeat nobis in debitis magni non, dolor aut libero
      dignissimos fugiat. Sed laboriosam itaque necessitatibus hic excepturi, perferendis, exercitationem cumque incidunt asperiores labore dolor.</p>
    <p>Minus velit rerum, reiciendis perspiciatis pariatur accusamus, magni voluptatibus, voluptatem fugit optio libero quidem! Nostrum pariatur eveniet ipsum obcaecati aperiam deleniti hic quam facilis reprehenderit dolor ipsam suscipit, quidem laboriosam
      impedit fugiat sit dignissimos delectus qui. Suscipit necessitatibus natus omnis eveniet molestiae nostrum aut culpa, tempora, voluptatibus modi eius nisi.</p>
    <p>Illo quo, iure doloremque unde ullam iste. Fuga ullam dicta voluptate, odio sint molestiae expedita sequi, placeat omnis porro. Blanditiis ut, laboriosam nobis necessitatibus esse ipsam, magnam facilis in placeat delectus quidem eos laborum, illum
      similique fugiat nesciunt doloremque ratione unde vel fugit excepturi dolor minima, amet tenetur. Tempora, eveniet.</p>
    <p>Aliquam ex assumenda eum perspiciatis odio suscipit nemo in delectus. Iste in, ipsam iure deserunt, explicabo ipsum maxime. Praesentium, vitae, quos quia sed doloribus laboriosam. Architecto sapiente totam quisquam esse saepe asperiores provident
      voluptatibus aperiam, similique sunt fugit cupiditate beatae aspernatur laborum, eius quas ab tempore consequatur officiis vero! Fugiat.</p>
    <p>Explicabo minima necessitatibus soluta odio, sunt saepe aspernatur quasi molestiae cum? Nulla eveniet ad accusantium sed sapiente quod ea soluta repellendus culpa, ut deleniti dolore. Porro amet, quasi dignissimos provident modi nihil rerum quis explicabo,
      voluptatem illo assumenda itaque. Maxime sequi asperiores enim tempora maiores dolor. Nihil quidem repudiandae asperiores!</p>
    <p>Dicta facere at dolorum ut veritatis recusandae praesentium nesciunt illo, omnis doloremque labore repellendus soluta officia distinctio aperiam pariatur minus quia placeat enim, amet, quae repellat reiciendis nihil magni. Ad expedita dolores cupiditate
      debitis dolore? Unde vitae inventore provident reiciendis adipisci dolorum ad ipsa possimus excepturi, mollitia nobis. Perspiciatis, voluptate.</p>
    <p>Officia minima nulla delectus neque sapiente in voluptates iste facere dolorum sequi, animi fuga illo enim alias explicabo, culpa? Quaerat nesciunt animi, eius assumenda quidem sunt saepe nam suscipit voluptate eaque, laborum minus expedita nostrum
      praesentium iusto eveniet officia ab tempore eos at. Dolores minus qui fugit, temporibus sequi tempora!</p>
    <a id="foo" name="foo">ID:foo</a>
  </div>

</body>
```